# Spring batch Job questions

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Spring batch job reading a large CV file and reading the records and send the message to the 3rd party to restful API. While running the Jobs some issue happened in the middle of the file and job abandon, Has there any way to start the job where it is left and process the remaining records instead of starting from scratch?

I need suggestions. Is there a way to avoid this behavior instead of processing the file again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restart failing job from the point where it failed. This is exactly where Spring Batch can help you.

But there are some design that you need to do upfront:

- use as much as possible `ItemReader`/`ItemProcessor`/`ItemWriter`. If you have bulk steps then you need to write your own restartable logic.
- Take care about your job's parameters. By default they are unique - so they are some kind of `Primary key` for your job. This enables you to start job with same parameters - the will be restarted then from last failed step.
- Spring batch saves counters for rows and step metadata in the database, so you want to have your database persistent.
- etc

There are plenty of things to explain here, so please read official documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#restartability